# How to optimize the tables in information_Schema database

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, information-schema, fragmentation

I got the free space (fragmentation issues) in my **information_Schema** database.

Alert shows that there are 1500% free space in some tables like **COLUMNS , ROUTINES.**

I am worried how this is possible because i don't have any routines in my database and how i can optimize the information_schema because its memory based database and created on the starting of mysql service.

Also when i query **"SHOW CREATE TABLE"** on any of the information_schema table it gives me innodb as engine of these table, but i think it should be memory.

Any idea to optimize these tables without restart?

Thanks

Comment: Start by showing us some specifics.  It may be a non-issue, or something that cannot be fixed.  From there, we can discuss possible actions.  For example, if it is 1500% of 1KB, I would consider that too small to be an issue.  But if that is 1GB, we should dig into the details.

Comment: i am searching for the reason for this. because i never created routines on this instance so why there is any of the free space.

Comment: InnoDB preallocates space in anticipation of more inserts/updates/etc.  This is a performance optimization.  The numbers you get from `information_schema` is only part of the "free" space that exists.  There is no way to get rid of such "wasted" space.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?  What ENGINE are those tables?

Answer (score 0):

When you have `innodb_file_per_table = OFF`, InnoDB tables are created in the system 'tablespace', `ibdata1`.  It could be that you have created and manipulated a lot of tables there.

`Data_free` is a confusing term in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and certain tables in `information_schema`...

- For MyISAM tables, it is an accurate amount of the space that could be recovered from the `.MYD` file (but not the `.MYI` file).
- For InnoDB it means one of 2 things...

  - If the table you are looking at was created with `innodb_file_per_table = ON`, then `Data_free` is *some* of the unused space.  Often, not all of it can be recovered by any means.
  - If the table you are looking at was created with `innodb_file_per_table = OFF`, then `Data_free` is the free space in `ibdata1`.  That free space will be used for new inserts and new tables, thereby decreasing `Data_free`.  However, the size of `ibdata1` cannot be shrunk, at least not without a lot of effort (dump everything, remove, reload).

Comment: On my copy of 5.6.12, I see 10 I_S tables that are MyISAM; zero that are InnoDB.  What version are you running?  How many of each do you see?

Comment: my version is mysql 5.7

Comment: Do `use information_schema; show table status;` -- how many are MyISAM; how many are InnoDB?